# create and assign a has many through relationship in devise signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-attributes

When a user signs up through devise, I am trying to create a new partner object, and then assign that relationship when the user is created. here is what I have currently:

**models/user.rb**

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable, :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :admin, :partner_ids, :provider, :uid

  #has_and_belongs_to_many :partners
  has_many :partners, :through => :partners_users
  has_many :partners_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :partners_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :partners

  def with_partner
    self.partners.build
    self
  end
```

**modes/partner.rb**

```
  attr_accessible :name, :address, :verified, :verification_code

  has_many :users, :through => :partners_users
  has_many :partners_users
  has_many :places
  has_many :offers
```

**sign up form**

registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
  
  
Account Information







 
  

  
Business Information

  
  

  
   5 %>

  
  
 "big fancy button" %>

currently when i submit the form I get the following error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: partner
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using accepts_nested_attributes with attr_accessible, you need to put the attributes in the attr_accessible:

```
attr_accessible :partner_attributes
```

Comment: so should this be in the user model or the partner model? I tried adding it to the user model and still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment).

Having `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `User` model enables you to send the data to the `Partner` model.

Then, in the User model, you have to set the requested `attr_accessible`.

```
attr_accessible : partner_attributes
```